# How to programmatically edit a text file?

Tags: python, txt

I have a file called "answer" with "NO" written in it.
But in a certain moment of my code I want to change it to "YES".

Doing this:

```
file = open("answer.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
read = file.read()
print(read)
```

The output is: **NO**

I know `mode = "a"` stands for *"to add"*, but I don't want to add a "YES", I want to erase the NO and write YES.

How do I edit a file, or a line in a file?

Comment: You have to close and reopen it with "w" to rewrite the file.

Comment: Minor (pedantic) correction: 'a' is for *append*.  'w' (write mode) first truncates (erases current content) then enables writing.

Comment: Opening in write mode will overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

> *mode = "a" stands for "to add", but I don't want to add a "YES", I want to erase the NO and write YES.*

You want to erase the previous content of the file? Use `'w'` mode!

```
file = open("answer.txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8")
file.write("YES")
file.close() # Now answer.txt contains only "YES"
```

To avoid calling that unestetic `file.close` you can take advantage of `_io.TextIOWrapper`'s method `__enter__` using a `with`/`as` block:

```
with open("answer.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write("YES")
```

---

You should know that `'a'` doesn't stand for *"add"* but for *"append"*, and that there are other options that you can find in the documentation [`here`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

---

> *How do I edit a file, **or a line in a file**?*

This second question is more complicated, you will have to do the following:

- Open the file
- Read the file
- Split the file in lines (or directly read it using `.readlines()`)
- Iterate through lines until you find the one you want to edit
- Edit the line
- Write to the file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mode='w'` to write in file, `mode='w'` will first erase the content if exists or create new file if not exists and then write the text you want to write.

And, use [`with`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/) syntax, so you don't need to close the file.

```py
with open("answer.txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    file.write("YES")
```