# How to change first character in each line of a text file?

Tags: python, txt

I want to change the first character on each line in the text file. Here is my code and my output but I don't know how to change and save that in the same text file.

```py
for rf in glob.glob('./labels/train/*'):
    read=open(rf,'r')
    t=read.readlines()
    for ind in t:
        print(ind[0])
```

I have got what I want but I don't know how to change that and save it in the same text file.

```
1
1
1
1
1
4
```

Comment: Check This [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162145/how-do-i-edit-a-txt-file-in-python/72162177#72162177)

Comment: One more thing, What is the data inside side your old file.

Comment: 1 0.7141610738255033 0.7547281921618205 0.401006711409396 

this is the data. I only want to change the first int. i want that first 1 to be zero on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:)

```py
for rf in glob.glob('./labels/train/*'):
    read=open(rf,'r')
    t=read.readlines()

    read.close()
    for_write = [str(int(ind[0])-1)+ind[1:] for ind in t]   
    write = open(rf,'w')
    write.writelines(for_write)
    write.close()
```

or using [`with`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/?msclkid=7c1ae7f7cede11ecb8299601db6838a5):)

```py
for rf in glob.glob('./labels/train/*'):
    with open('test.txt','r')as read:
        t=read.readlines()
        for_write = [str(int(ind[0])-1)+ind[1:] for ind in t]
    with open('test.txt','w') as write:
        write.writelines(for_write)
```

Comment: It does not change the values and deletes other values in txt file.

Comment: I want to change only the first char. others should be the same. i want to subtract 1 on every first int on each line.

Comment: @tornike you want `1 23423.34 23424` to `0 23423.34 23424` am I right or not.

Comment: yes. exactly. on each line. one more problem is that , these numbers in txt are string